# Resize Mac OS Plus partition without losing data

Tags: macos, partitioning, formatting

I have a 1000G external hard disk formatted with Mac OS plus. It is a Omega drive, which came by default with that format. Now I have 200G free space and would like to reformat this free space to NTFS. Is it possible to resize the partition without losing the 800G data?

Comment: In case you want to do FAT, or have other ideas on how to do this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82687/how-can-i-modify-an-existing-fat-partition-without-losing-its-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app` for that. It allows non-destructive resizing of partitions. See for example [this article](http://macs.about.com/od/applications/ss/diskutilitysize.htm) on how to do this. Alternatively, you can use the `diskutil` command line tool, [see here](http://www.macgeekery.com/tips/cli/nondestructively_resizing_volumes).

Although it's possible to resize without data loss, you should always have a backup at least of your more important data on that disk. Power outages and system crashes while reformatting a disk aren't fun.

Once your HFS+ partition's size is reduced, you can create a new partition in the empty space (though you cannot create NTFS partitions from OS X).

Comment: If you need write-access to NTFS partitions, you should look into Tuxera NTFS (http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) or Paragon NTFS (http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/); both are commercial products and work reliably.  There is also an open source solution (MacFuse) but the commercial programs are (IMO) worth their price.  One word of caution, if you do have a writeable NTFS partition, you may need to exclude it for spotlight: the combination of NTFS driver, bootcamp partition, and spotlight can thrash (I/O) a Mac into unusability.

Comment: @Robert While true, how is that related to either the question or this answer?

Comment: It is a comment on the answer. That "you cannot create NTFS partitions from OS X" is true for stock OS/X installations; for anyone to whom this is an important issue, they should be advised that there are good options that enable this.  I added the comment so anyone researching options for running a dual-format system would know the conclusion that OS/X cannot format or write to NTFS partitions is not the final word on the subject.  (I did up-vote your answer, BTW).

Comment: @Robert Ah I see, OK. I'm afraid I didn't read my own answer too well then when I wondered what you referred to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is a option in disk utility to create NTFS partition if you have installed Tuxera. Though I have not tried this method to partition yet. 
Ty,
Greenmen